# How can build two X axes in the same series in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want two x axis in same series in Highcharts first is this in top and second in bottom as in the example

(https://d2mvzyuse3lwjc.cloudfront.net/doc/en/QuickHelp/images/How_do_I_add_a_second_nonlinear_x_or_y_axis_to_my_graph_layer/Image020new.gif?v=37680)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by adding the second x-axis which is opposite and linked to the first (main) one. Check demo and code posted below.

**Code:**

```
  xAxis: [{

  }, {
    linkedTo: 0,
    opposite: true
  }]
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uswx8qao/1/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.opposite
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.linkedTo